# Is it possible to reuse/call a handler in C# Website from C# WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, ashx

I have an ASP.NET website that contains a number of handlers (.ashx). Is it possible to call that handler from a standalone C# REST API (Web API)? Or does it need to be in the same solution file?

[image]

For example, my handler file contains the following code

```
public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {

            base.ProcessRequest(context);
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
            try
            {
                string action = context.Request["action"] ?? "";
                switch (action.ToUpper())
                {
                    case GETDATA:
                        GetDataActions(context);
                        break;

                    case SETDATA:
                        SetDataActions(context);
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new Exception("");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception genericException)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                WriteResponse(context, xError.ToString());
            }
        }
```

I would like to call SETDATA action from my WEB API controller.
Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Have you considered moving all handlers in a separate assembly, which can be shared between your web application and web API as a common piece of code? Or does it have to be only in web API or in web application?

Comment: Only a few handlers are required for Web API so separate assembly is likely too much.

Comment: You need some intermediate container where you can store common code and reuse it across web application as well as API. If you plan to keep your common code in web application and then call it from API, you will have to add reference to your web application dll (or vice versa, if you decide to refer API from your web application). That definitely does not sound great. Binds API and web app too tightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse the handlers by calling them like a WebApi.

Make sure you have configured the handlers in your .config file and define a routing for them.

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="[verb list]" path="[path/wildcard]" type="[COM+ Class], [Assembly]" validate="[true/false]" />
    <remove verb="[verb list]" path="[path/wildcard]" />
    <clear />
</httpHandlers>
```

Find more info here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/development/http-modules-handlers

> ANOTHER OPTION: You can reuse the handlers by packaging them as a library
> then use it in different projects. A nugget package for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WebClient` to call your ashx files such as:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
var content = client.DownloadString("http://yoursite.com/AttachReport.ashx");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below:

```
    static async Task<Uri> CreateProductAsync(Product product)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
            "api/products", product);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // return URI of the created resource.
        return response.Headers.Location;
    }
```

Detail link from microsoft: [Calling a web api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)